# Remove numbering of subtables

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, pander

I´m using pander to split a wide table (too many columns) into many tables.

```
pander(df, table.split.table=80,style='rmarkdown',table.emphasize.rownames,caption="caption")
```

I´ve read that a good way to do it is to use the following latex command that should decrease numbering of subtables. In my case i have 4 consecutive tables after splitting the wide table.

```
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
```

Is there a way to do this directly by calling pander ?? The thing is that i´m using knitR markdown and pander and don´t know how to add it ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Yes, although it will be a LaTeX/PDF-only solution, but what @mb21 suggested below should work.

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc [supports raw TeX](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-tex), so just put `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` in your markdown source after each table, just as you would in LaTeX...

Comment: How do you put this command after each subtable, when they are created automatically by `pander()` ?